# Eclipse RCP Application, passing data to a command

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I'm fairly new to eclipse and I'm trying to write a simple RCP application to automatically generate configuration files for routers etc.

I have a wizard which gathers the required information (such as IP address) and then updates a model with the users input.  When the wizard finishes it triggers the model to write out the file.

On my last wizard page I prompt the user to save the file and have a "Browse" button which launches a command that displays a 'save' **FileDialog**.  The command is called when the button is clicked:

```
browseButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {

        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e){

            IHandlerService handlerService = (IHandlerService) (PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getService(IHandlerService.class));
            try {
                filename = (String) handlerService.executeCommand("ie.btireland.cm.config.projectFileAs", null);
                path.setText(filename);
                setPageComplete(true);
            }catch(Exception E){ // handle error }
        }
});
```

Everything works ok however I wish to pass a String object to the command so it can use it on `FileDialog.setFileName()` when I create the dialog.  My goal is for the suggested file name to be already populated when the FileDialog window appears.

I've been around the block searching for an answer and I just can't work it out.  As the command is only referenced by its ID I can't work out how to pass a variable to it.

I gave up in the end and I now write the string out to a temporary file which I read in the command handler, but obviously that is a crazy solution.  Surely there must be a simpler way?

Any help would be most appreciated,

Cathal.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for parameterized commands as described in this [wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Platform_Command_Framework#Executing_a_command_with_parameters) and this [article](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseCommandsAdvanced/article.html#parameters). The former concentrates on the programmatic invocation, while the latter provides a thorough explanation of the declarative side of parameterized commands.